Checking DataCard Values and Conditionally Displaying A Warning Page
I have a canvas app that I'm using to add shift inspection records to a SharePoint list. It adds the data to the list correctly; however, if the user selects an item as "Not OK", I want a warning screen to be displayed after the form data has been submitted to the SP list.
The form has comboboxes where the use selects OK or Not OK.
Below is the code that I currently have, but doesn't display the warning screen (scrDNO).
The variable used (varIsNotOK) is defined as a global variable and initialized as false
If(
    DataCardValue17.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue18.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue19.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue20.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue21.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue22.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue23.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue24.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue25.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue26.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue27.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue28.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue29.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue30.Selected.Value = "Not OK", 
    varIsNotOK = true, 
    varIsNotOK = false
    );
If(
    varIsNotOK = true,
    SubmitForm(frmPJInsp);Navigate(scrDNO),
    SubmitForm(frmPJInsp) ;Navigate(Main)
    )

Any help at all with this or even direction where I may be going wrong would be very appreciated.

There might be a more efficient way but what I figured out was that I can't simply say varIsNotOK = true it has to be set using the Set() function as shown in the code below
If(
    DataCardValue17.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue18.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue19.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue20.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue21.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue22.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue23.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue24.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue25.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue26.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue27.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue28.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue29.Selected.Value = "Not OK" 
    Or 
    DataCardValue30.Selected.Value = "Not OK", 
    Set (varIsNotOK,true), 
    Set (varIsNotOK,false)
    );

Switch(
    varIsNotOK,
        true,SubmitForm(frmPJInsp);Navigate(scrDNO),
        false,SubmitForm(frmPJInsp) ;Navigate(Main)
    )

